# Nested Relationships in DRF Serializers

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

*AttributeError at /api/register/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_profile` on serializer `UserRegistrationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `UserProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'user_profile'*.

**UserProfile model looks like this**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_phone_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    email_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

**serializers.py file looks like this**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core import validators



class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=50,
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your name.',
            'max_length': 'Please enter a valid name.'
        }
    )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=50,
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your name.',
            'max_length': 'Please enter a valid name.'
        }
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter a username.',
            'max_length': 'Username should be no more than 30 characters.',
            'unique': 'This username is already taken. Please choose a different one.',
        }
    )

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        max_length=50,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your email address.',
            'max_length': 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        }
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        write_only=True,
        max_length=128,  # Maximum length for Django password
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter a password.',
            'max_length': 'Password should be no more than 128 characters.'
        },
        validators=[
            validators.MinLengthValidator(8, message='Password must be at least 8 characters.'),
            validators.RegexValidator(
                regex=r'[A-Z]',
                message='Password must contain at least one uppercase letter.',
                code='invalid_password'
            ),
            validators.RegexValidator(
                regex=r'[a-z]',
                message='Password must contain at least one lowercase letter.',
                code='invalid_password'
            ),
            validators.RegexValidator(
                regex=r'[0-9]',
                message='Password must contain at least one number.',
                code='invalid_password'
            ),
            validators.RegexValidator(
                regex=r'[!@#$%^&*()]',
                message='Password must contain at least one special character.',
                code='invalid_password'
            )
        ]
    )

    registration_date = serializers.DateTimeField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(datetime.now())
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'registration_date')


class UserProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=20,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())],
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your phone number.',
            'max_length': 'Please enter a valid phone number.',
            'unique': 'This phone number is already taken. Please choose a different one.',
        }
    )

    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(
        required=True,
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your date of birth.'
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['phone_number', 'date_of_birth']



class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserModelSerializer(required=True)
    user_profile = UserProfileModelSerializer(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile')

        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **user_profile_data)
        return user_profile

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'user_profile')
```

**views.py file looks like this**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import UserRegistrationSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
# Create your views here.


class RegisterAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            # print(serializer.data)
            serializer.save()

            # user = serializer.save()
            # refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            # return Response({
            #     'refresh': str(refresh),
            #     'access': str(refresh.access_token),
            #     'user': serializer.data
            # }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you are using a ModelSerializer in UserRegistrationSerializer with the model UserProfile that does not have the user_profile in their fields so that the reason why you are getting an AttributeError.

If you want to use a field that is not in the model that you set in the ModelSerializer you have to declare a get method for the field, in your case

```
def get_user_profile(self, obj):
    # Process to obtain the data for the field user profile
    return field_data
```

Or you use a serializers.Serializer instead of a ModelSerializer, the ModelSerializer validate that all the fields on the serializer are in the model too.